# How do I correctly manually recreate sklearn (python) logistic regression predict_proba outcome for multiple classification

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

If I run a basic logistic regression with 4 classes, I can get the predict_proba array.

How can i manually calculate the probabilities using the coefficients and intercepts?   What are the exact steps to get the same answers that predict_proba generates?

There seem to be multiple questions about this online and several suggestions which are either incomplete or don't match up anyway.

For example, I can't replicate this process from my sklearn model so what is missing?

https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/code/manually-generate-predicted-probabilities-from-a-multinomial-logistic-regression-in-stata/

Thanks,

Comment: You can check the source code on scikit learn GitHub

Answer (score 3):

Because I had the same question but could not find an answer that gave the same results I had a look at the [sklearn GitHub repository](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn) to find the answer. Using the functions from their own package I was able to create the same results I got from `predict_proba()`.

**It appears that sklearn uses a special `softmax()` function that differs from the usual softmax function in their code.**

Let's assume you build a model like this:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X = ...
Y = ...
model = LogisticRegression(multi_class="multinomial", solver="saga")
model.fit(X, Y)
```

Then you can calculate the probabilities either with `model.predict(X)` or use the sklearn function mentioned above to calculate them manually like this.

```
from sklearn.utils.extmath import softmax, 
import numpy as np

scores = np.dot(X, model.coef_.T) + model.intercept_
softmax(scores)  # Sklearn implementation
```

In the documentation for their own `softmax()` function, they note that

> The softmax function is calculated by
>
> np.exp(X) / np.sum(np.exp(X), axis=1)
>
> This will cause overflow when large values are exponentiated. Hence
>   the largest value in each row is subtracted from each data point to
>   prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

Replicate sklearn calcs (saw this on a different post):

```
V = X_train.values.dot(model.coef_.transpose())
U = V + model.intercept_
A = np.exp(U)
P=A/(1+A)
P /= P.sum(axis=1).reshape((-1, 1))
```

seems slightly different than softmax calcs, or the UCLA stat example, but it works.

Comment: This does not give me the same results as sklearn's predict_proba().