# Multinomial Logistic Regression get probabilities using model coefficients and intercepts

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, multinomial

I have a 5 class multinomial logistic regression `model = LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial', solver='lbfgs')`  using sklearn and I would like to achieve the same output as `model.predict_prob()` just using the coefficients and intercepts.

```
# model.classes_
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

# model.coef_
 array([[ 0.07011634, -0.01660448, -0.02280068, -0.0142022 , -0.02046682],
        [-0.0165452 ,  0.06987072, -0.00576749, -0.01930324, -0.01419374],
        [-0.01615717, -0.01411199,  0.07353034, -0.01734335, -0.01666161],
        [-0.01659975, -0.02089339, -0.01998879,  0.06762984, -0.02415484],
        [-0.02081421, -0.01826086, -0.02497338, -0.01678105,  0.07547701]])
   
# model.intercept_
 array([ 0.10282811, -0.12500906, -0.0892085 ,  0.14219192, -0.03080247]))
```

For a given row

`X[0] = array([14.4429439 ,  9.89014464, 13.20301328, 14.79792498,  9.61442853])`

how can I get the probabilities of each class using the model `coef_` and `intercept_` to be the same as below?

`model.predict_proba([X[0]])`

```
array([[0.24858766, 0.16423193, 0.2136478 , 0.23815396, 0.13537864]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer.

```py
from sklearn.utils.extmath import softmax
import numpy as np

scores = np.dot([X[0]], model.coef_.T) + model.intercept_
softmax(scores)  # Sklearn implementation
```

Comment: Answer found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60172051/18158000